# I want to count a non empty rows of a particular column from one excel workbook and update it to another

Tags: vba, excel

```
Dim count As Integer
Dim myData As Workbook
Dim col As Range, rng As Range, n#, b#
Set col = Columns(1) 'choose the column to count the values from           
SetmyData=Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\cas\Book3.xlsx")'selecting a workbook'
        Worksheets("sheet1").Select
            Set rng = Intersect(col, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
            On Error Resume Next
                b = rng.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).count'applying the count function'
                n = rng.Cells.count - b - 1
            On Error GoTo 0
        Worksheets("sheet1").Select
        count = n
        Set myData = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\cas\Book2.xlsx")'used to update the data in another workbook
        Worksheets("sheet1").Select
```

I am not able to select the workbook to apply count algo.
run time error-  application defined or object defined error

Comment: `SetmyData` should be `Set myData`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will get you the count of the None-Empty cells in Column "A" in "sheet1" in `myData` Workbook.

You can avoid all the unnecessary `Select`, which slows down your code run-time.

Also, you can use the `WorksheetFunction.CountA` function to count the number of cells in a range that are not empty.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub CountNonEmptyCells()

Dim MyCount As Long
Dim myData As Workbook    
Dim Rng As Range

Set myData = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\cas\Book3.xlsx") ' selecting a workbook'
With myData.Worksheets("sheet1")
    Set Rng = Intersect(.Columns(1), .UsedRange)
    MyCount = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rng)
End With

End Sub
```